# Smart Thermostat (Nest, Honeywell or Ecobee) from KMC wiring?

Tags: wiring, thermostat, nest

I moved into a 1br condo recently and was looking to update the thermostat to Nest (or other Smart home thermostat). The current thermostat model is KMC and when I took off the casing, the wiring does not match the typical Y/G/W/C/R outputs. I tried reaching out to Nest and Ecobee for guidance but have hit a dead end. Further searches have shown that the Right side of the image could match to R/W/Y2/Y1/R/ O/B / G; but I'm not sure what the left side wiring would connect to. Has anyone come across this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: How is the system hooked up at the other end?

Comment: Is this a radiant heat system, forced air, or something elsr?

Comment: always take pictures "head on" to the wiring, not at an angle like you did. ... also KMC Controls is the manufacturer, not a model number. ... what is the model of the thermostat